# why my EA does not buy and sell automatically?

Tags: mql5

I have an EA, I want to do a back test on it in MetaTrader5, I select my EA in strategy tester section and adjust the settings, when I hit start the back testing begins and the chart starts moving but my EA does not buy and sell automatically, I don't know what the problem is, would you please help me to fix this code? Here is my code:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Property                                                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property strict
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Global variables                                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
input int MA_Period = 50; // Period for the moving average
input double Risk_Percentage = 1.5; // Adjusted risk percentage per trade
input double Stop_Loss = 100.0; // Initial stop loss in points
input double Take_Profit = 200.0; // Take profit level in points
double LotSize; // Position size based on risk
int Digits; // Number of decimal places for the symbol
double AccountBalance = 10000.0; // Account balance in USD

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
   Digits = int(SymbolInfoInteger(_Symbol, SYMBOL_DIGITS)); // Get the number of decimal places for the symbol
   LotSize = CalculatePositionSize(); // Calculate initial lot size
   
   Print("Expert Advisor initialized successfully.");
   
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
   Print("Expert Advisor deinitialized successfully.");
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
   double closePrice[]; // Declare 'closePrice' as an array

   if (Bars(_Symbol, 0) < MA_Period + 2) // Check if there is enough historical data
      return;

   if (!CopyClose(_Symbol, 0, 1, 1, closePrice))
   {
      Print("Error copying Close price: ", GetLastError());
      return;
   }

   double ma = iMA(_Symbol, 0, MA_Period, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE);
   
   if (closePrice[1] < ma && closePrice[0] > ma && closePrice[1] < closePrice[0] - 10) // Add condition to check price trend and other sophisticated entry conditions
   {
      MqlTradeRequest request;
      request.action = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;
      request.magic = 123456;
      request.symbol = _Symbol;
      request.volume = LotSize; // Use calculated lot size
      request.price = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK);
      request.type = ORDER_TYPE_BUY;
      request.type_filling = ORDER_FILLING_FOK;
      
      double Point = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT); // Define Point
      
      request.tp = NormalizeDouble(closePrice[0] + CalculateTakeProfit() * Point, Digits); // Set dynamic take profit level
      request.sl = NormalizeDouble(closePrice[0] - CalculateStopLoss() * Point, Digits); // Set dynamic stop loss level

      MqlTradeResult result;

      if (!OrderSend(request, result))
      {
         Print("Buy OrderSend error: ", GetLastError());
         return;
      }
   }
   else if (closePrice[1] > ma && closePrice[0] < ma && closePrice[1] > closePrice[0] + 10) // Add condition to check price trend and other sophisticated entry conditions
   {  
      MqlTradeRequest request;
      request.action = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;
      request.magic = 123456;
      request.symbol = _Symbol;
      request.volume = LotSize; // Use calculated lot size
      request.price = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_BID);
      request.type = ORDER_TYPE_SELL;
      request.type_filling = ORDER_FILLING_FOK;

      double Point = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT); // Define Point
      
      request.tp = NormalizeDouble(closePrice[0] - CalculateTakeProfit() * Point, Digits); // Set dynamic take profit level
      request.sl = NormalizeDouble(closePrice[0] + CalculateStopLoss() * Point, Digits); // Set dynamic stop loss level

      MqlTradeResult result;

      if (!OrderSend(request, result))
      {
         Print("Sell OrderSend error: ", GetLastError());
         return;
      }
   }
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Calculate dynamic stop loss based on market conditions           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double CalculateStopLoss()
{
    double tick_value = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE);
    double tick_size = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE);
    
    return ((AccountBalance * Risk_Percentage / (LotSize * Stop_Loss)) / (tick_value * tick_size));
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Calculate dynamic take profit based on market conditions         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double CalculateTakeProfit()
{
    double tick_value = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE);
    double tick_size = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE);

    return ((AccountBalance * Risk_Percentage / (LotSize * Take_Profit)) / (tick_value * tick_size));
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Calculate dynamic position size based on risk percentage and stop loss|
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double CalculatePositionSize()
{
    double tick_value = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE);
    double tick_size = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE);
    
    double riskAmount = AccountBalance * Risk_Percentage;
    double maxLoss = riskAmount * LotSize * Stop_Loss;
    
    return NormalizeDouble(maxLoss / (tick_value * tick_size), 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using the old ordersend from mq4.

Please check the documentation for mq5 here:

https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/trading/ordersend

Instead of passing the parameters to OrderSend, you will define an MQLTradeRequest and an MQLTradeResult and assign their parameters, and then you will pass them into OrderSend like this:

```
// Calculate the previous values of the Moving Averages
double ma8_prev = iMA(Symbol(), 0, 8, 1, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE);
double ma21_prev = iMA(Symbol(), 0, 21, 1, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE);

// Check if MA8 cuts MA21 from below with micrometer precision for Buy signal
if (IsCutFromBelow(ma8_current, ma21_current) && IsCutFromAbove(ma8_prev, ma21_prev))
{
    // Check for additional confirmation before placing a Buy order
    if (IsAdditionalConfirmationMet())
    {
        double lotSize = CalculateLotSize(); // Calculate dynamic lot size based on account balance and risk

        // Place a Buy order with precise entry and set Stop Loss/Take Profit
        double stopLossPrice = Bid - StopLossPips * Point;
        double takeProfitPrice = Bid + TakeProfitPips * Point;

        MqlTradeRequest request;
        MqlTradeResult result;
        ZeroMemory(request);
        ZeroMemory(result);

        request.action = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;
        request.symbol = Symbol();
        request.volume = lotSize;
        request.price = Bid;
        request.sl = stopLossPrice;
        request.tp = takeProfitPrice;
        request.type = ORDER_TYPE_BUY;
        request.type_filling = ORDER_FILLING_FOK;

        if (OrderSend(request, result))
        {
            if (result.retcode == TRADE_RETCODE_DONE)
            {
                Print("Buy order placed successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                HandleError("Buy", result.retcode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HandleError("Buy", GetLastError());
        }
    }
}

// Check if MA8 cuts MA21 from above with micrometer precision for Sell signal
if (IsCutFromAbove(ma8_current, ma21_current) && IsCutFromBelow(ma8_prev, ma21_prev))
{
    // Check for additional confirmation before placing a Sell order
    if (IsAdditionalConfirmationMet())
    {
        double lotSize = CalculateLotSize(); // Calculate dynamic lot size based on account balance and risk

        // Place a Sell order with precise entry and set Stop Loss/Take Profit
        double stopLossPrice = Ask + StopLossPips * Point;
        double takeProfitPrice = Ask - TakeProfitPips * Point;

        MqlTradeRequest request;
        MqlTradeResult result;
        ZeroMemory(request);
        ZeroMemory(result);

        request.action = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;
        request.symbol = Symbol();
        request.volume = lotSize;
        request.price = Ask;
        request.sl = stopLossPrice;
        request.tp = takeProfitPrice;
        request.type = ORDER_TYPE_SELL;
        request.type_filling = ORDER_FILLING_FOK;

        if (OrderSend(request, result))
        {
            if (result.retcode == TRADE_RETCODE_DONE)
            {
                Print("Sell order placed successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                HandleError("Sell", result.retcode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HandleError("Sell", GetLastError());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will help you out where I can. For your updated question, you are trying to assign a value of 0 to the action field of the MqlTradeRequest struct. The action field can only be assigned values from the ENUM_TRADE_REQUEST_ACTIONS enumeration. You should be able to initialize the struct with all 0s by doing this instead:
`
MqlTradeRequest request;
ZeroMemory(request);
`